# How to fix a cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem using a PutObject in AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

First and foremost, I am a total noob when it comes to using Amazon's SDK for PHP so bare with me. I am trying to follow along with a video tutorial on how to upload a file to an AWS S3 bucket using PHP and the AWS SDK.

I have all of the correct information to start the process but I get the following error when trying to upload the file on my localhost instance:

Error uploading files: Error executing "PutObject" on "https://bregg.s3.amazonaws.com/uploadme.txt"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://bregg.s3.amazonaws.com/uploadme.txt

Why is AWS looking for a SSL local issuer cert on my dev laptop?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

This error happens after I hit the upload button on the webpage.

Comment: It's easier to understand the issue if you provide your current code.

Comment: I will work on getting that. Thanks!